# How can i make a working responsive gallery?

Tags: html, css

I need to make a responsive gallery with two rows and 5 thumbnails on each row. I think I did something wrong cause the first row works fine but then instead of a new row underneath, it goes down the right side.I can't even make the thumbnails smaller without it changing the entire look. Can you please help me make my gallery work? I will put an image of the way it looks now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <style>
 .container {
    display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 20px;
  
}

.box > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
 
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
}


.box .title {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .5rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .5rem;
}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
              <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
              <div class="title">
                <span>Image Title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
              <div class="title">
                <span>Image Title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
              <div class="title">
                <span>Image Title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
              <div class="title">
                <span>Image Title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
              <div class="title">
                <span>Image Title</span>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <img src="placeholder-image.png" alt="some alt text">
                <div class="title">
                  <span>Image Title</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Vote to close because `div` missing on 5th box

Comment: Hi, if there is something wrong with the code, you can simply point it out so I can learn instead of wanting to close my question.

Comment: Yes but this is a problem here. So this is a reason to close the question. And it solves your problem. SO rules

Comment: thanks then i guess :))

Answer (score 1):

Try this HTML code. You were missing a closing `</div>` after the 5th box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(230px, 1fr));
      gap: 10px;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .box>img {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
      border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
      transform: scale(1.04);
    }
    
    .box .title {
      background: #ddd;
      padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      width: -webkit-fill-available;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="https://sppagebuilder.com/addons/image/image1.jpg" alt="some alt text" />
      <div class="title">
        <span>Image Title</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```